# How can I download a 33gb file from Google Drive?

Tags: download, file-transfer, google-drive

I have many files I want to download. I managed to get a 18gb file downloaded by signing up for a google account. There is also larger files, first of which is 33gb and I cannot figure out how to download it. The download stops somewhere around two thirds way through. Browser claims "couldn't download - network issue", every time. Resuming gives error "couldn't download - no permission". I have tried pausing it when it is halfway complete and resuming hours later but again it won't resume. Files sized 11-12gb I can download one after the other, all day. The problem must be the quota. I only have 15gb space in my account so I can't do the "copy file" trick for this 33gb one. I wanna know if it's even possible at all.

Comment: You haven't explained what's the problem?

Comment: edited the question

Comment: Have you try to use Google Disk software?

Comment: This probably belongs on webapps rather than here, as it's likely a google limitation, not computer… unless you're trying to do this with a browser. Use a downloader instead. Browsers don't handle large files well.

Comment: @RomeoNinov No I have not. This should do the trick? Tell me, where can I find it?

Comment: https://www.google.com/intl/en/drive/download/

Comment: @Tetsujin What downloaders can do this?

Comment: @Bricktop, first try native client, then downloaders

Comment: @RomeoNinov Oh you mean Google Drive! I had trouble finding Google Disk. Yea I have it but how is that supposed to help?

Comment: @Bricktop, logging with the credentials for this file you should be able to download it locally.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I do not understand any of that. The file is an 'anyone with a link' sort of thing. How exactly do I 'download it locally'? From webapp or desktop?

Comment: If it's not shared with you explicitly try to use download manager.

Comment: @RomeoNinov please expand on that too. Are you talking about browser extension? I tried a few already but none of them can find links for those files in the shared directory.